# Android Google API platform 4.0 download?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I have searched alot for downloadable zip of Android Google API 4.0 onwards.I did not found it on developer.android.com website also.

Where as I found sdk platforms 4.0 above on some external link http://www.hariadi.org/android/manual-download-of-android-sdk-components/ 
. But it has some problem when trying to create AVD.

Anyways I am looking for Google API instead. Where can i find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download and manage all avaliable versions of AVDs and other tools from official google SDK manager:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: sdk manager is not showing Google API for platform 4.0 at all. I have latest SDK tools and ADT 20.0

Comment: very strange, because i can see 4.0 google api, check if you have the newest version of sdk tools

Comment: can you please check your repository link? Would appreciate if u could provide it.

Comment: check if you've selected Updates/New and Installed positions in sdk manager(look at attached screenshot). If you can't find this sdk i can upload this folder to the net and send you a link

Comment: I had to go to Help -> check for new Updates And then I installed ADT 20.0 from there. Now it is showing Google API and others API's in SDK manager. Thanks.